# Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic (3.16.0-34.47) over (3.16.0-34.45)

Tags: apt, package-management, java, dpkg

I want to change Java 8 to Java 7. I planned to Remove Java 8 First. I run the Following cmd

> sudo apt-get purge oracle-java8-installer

I got the Following Error

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     linux-signed-image-3.16.0-34-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic (= 3.16.0-34.47) but 3.16.0-34.45 is to be installed
     oracle-java8-set-default : Depends: oracle-java8-installer but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

and try with

> apt-get -f install

i got following Errors

```
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Correcting dependencies... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      linux-headers-3.16.0-31 linux-headers-3.16.0-31-generic linux-image-3.16.0-31-generic linux-image-extra-3.16.0-31-generic linux-signed-image-3.16.0-31-generic
    Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
    The following extra packages will be installed:
      linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic
    Suggested packages:
      fdutils linux-doc-3.16.0 linux-source-3.16.0 linux-tools
    The following packages will be upgraded:
      linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic
    1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 142 not upgraded.
    6 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/16.2 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    (Reading database ... 405456 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic_3.16.0-34.47_amd64.deb ...
    Done.
    Unpacking linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic (3.16.0-34.47) over (3.16.0-34.45) ...
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic_3.16.0-34.47_amd64.deb (--unpack):
     cannot copy extracted data for './boot/System.map-3.16.0-34-generic' to '/boot/System.map-3.16.0-34-generic.dpkg-new': unexpected end of file or stream
    dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
    Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 3.16.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-34-generic
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-3.16.0-34-generic_3.16.0-34.47_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am not able to Install Java 7 also. Whats my Problem ? how can resolve from this ? Please Help

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo apt-get update` before `sudo apt-get -f install`. A [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1445031) perhaps